# Resque call is getting stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am new to Resque. I want to make and send an excel file with the help of a Resque worker. I I have written that code in worker class. Now I have called the worker inside the controller function as:

```
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => "#{Rails.configuration.redis_machine}", :port => Rails.configuration.redis_port)

Resque.enqueue(MakeAndSend,records,email)
```

Here records is rows of data that are to be printed to the excel file and email is the mail id of the user to which this excel file is to be sent.

But the problem is that my code is get stuck at this line, the following line is getting executed only when the job is over. But as far as I understood from studying resque that the following line should execute immediately.

So if anyone helps me to figure this out, I will be really grateful.

EDIT Here above records is actually collection of objects. So I don't have any option to send ids here. Also, the redis server is not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, I don't think it would be that line which is the problem - it will likely be something behind that line, such as the worker file or something

I can see one main issue you'll likely have, and there will be others:

-> You're passing variables (ActiveRecord objects) to the Resque queue -- it's convention to send the id's of the variables so the worker file can call the databases when it runs

---

Here is some live code for our Resque queues:

```
  #app/models/message.rb (this gets called when we run "send_broadcast" function)
  def broadcast!
                self.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
                        Resque.enqueue(MailoutQueue, id, subscriber.id)
                end
        end

#app/workers/mailout_queue.rb
class MailoutQueue
        @queue = :mailer
        def self.perform(message_id, recipient_id)
                MessageMailer.send_message(message_id, recipient_id).deliver
        end
end
```

`MessageMailer.rb` is just a standard message sender file

---

If you can post your worker file code, it will help us appreciate where the real issue maybe, so we can fix appropriately!

Comment: Actually I don't have any option to send ids here, I am passing here collection of objects, actually records is collection of objects. An another thing, my Redis server is not getting hit.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Can you describe the collection of objects you're sending? As you can see from our code above, we cycle through the variables to get the id for each & send that to Redis. If you can explain why you're using the variables rather than ID's it will be much more helpful!

Comment: Yes actually records = Students.all(:condition => {...}), that I have passed as parameter in worker. Here I have to make an xls file with all ids, so sending individual id will not work here, I think. So is this wrong?

Comment: I think it's wrong, yes. Enqueuing just takes an instruction & the worker performs the required calls & functions. Sending an ActiveRecord Object is inefficient & will take up memory you don't need. A better way to do it will be to take the `records` variable and only call it in the worker. This will allow you to build the data as required. Yes, it will take more queries, but it will be much easier on Resque

Comment: Also, you must remember Redis (which is how Resque stores the Queue data) is a `key-value store`, meaning that it can only store ID's & other one-dimensional data